# How to hide automatically generated columns in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I've automatically populated a DataGrid from a DataTable from a SQL server. I want the user to be able to add or remove which columns are visible. I originally tried this:

```
    public void populateTaskTable(DataTable dt)
    {                    
        //add the whole datatable to the datagrid
        dg.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;

        dg.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

For a corresponding xaml (I've tried both with and without the `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`

```
           <DataGrid Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 

                    <!-- <DataGrid.Columns></DataGrid.Columns> -->

            </DataGrid>
```

Which resulted in a memory violation break. So then I did

```
MessageBox.Show(dg.Columns.Count());
```

to see if Columns was being populated, which it wasn't, it output a `0` even though I could see the columns in the program.

I found out [from this previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17484031/2374028) that "automatically generated columns are not added to the Columns index".

Then [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544778/how-to-force-datagrid-to-rebuild-visualtree-for-its-columns) I tried updating the DataGrid to get Columns populated like so

```
   taskTable.UpdateLayout();
```

and

```
   taskTable.Items.Refresh();
```

Which didn't do anything.

Is there a way to access the properties of an automatically generated DataGrid, or a way to add all of the columns of the DataGrid to the `Columns` component?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've updated my answer, linked answer is wrong. It links to msdn docs for Web not Wpf. I dropped a comment below that answer for future readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hook up the [AutoGeneratingColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event and hide the column over there.

```
dataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn += dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn;

void dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    e.Column.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

You may need to conditionally hide the columns, you can use

```
private void DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "YourProperty")
    {
        e.Column.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Or you can use [AutoGeneratedColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratedcolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event. It will be fired when all the columns has been generated.

```
dataGrid.AutoGeneratedColumns += DataGrid1_AutoGeneratedColumns;

void DataGrid1_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int columnsCount = DataGrid1.Columns.Count;
     //You can access the columns here.
}
```

The link you referred says that *Automatically generated columns are not added to the Columns collection.* I just noticed that *Auto generated columns are indeed added to the collection.* It is poor answer that links to the documentation of `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid` which is very wrong.

Comment: Thanks or your response! This code hides all the columns though. How I do I specifiy columns like this?

Comment: Check if the column is for your property like this `if (e.PropertyName == "YourPropertyName")`. I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use a static method where you pass in the grid and list of column names like this:

> ```
>     public static void CollapseGridColumns(DataGrid grid, List<string> columnNames)
>     {
>         foreach (var column in grid.Columns)
>         {
>             foreach(string columnName in columnNames)
>             {
>                 if (column.Header.ToString().ToLower() == columnName.ToLower())
>                 {
>                     column.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
>                     break;
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```