# How to output List as string using WPF DataGrid with auto generated columns

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datagrid

I am building a WPF application where a user will upload a file and the application will parse that file into a list of "Template" objects.

```
List<Template> templates = GetTemplates();
```

After parsing the file into a list of Template objects, I am setting the DataSource property of the DataGrid and allowing it to auto-generate the columns based on the object's properties.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="202" Width="809" Margin="233,85,0,0"/>

dataGrid.IsReadOnly = true;
dataGrid.ItemsSource = templates;
```

A few of the object's properties are of type List. In the DataGrid, the data for these columns show as "(Collection)". You can see it here:

[image]

```
public class Template
{
    public int TemplateId { get; set; }
    public List<string> ErrorMessages { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

So my question is, what's the easiest way for me make it display the list of strings as a concatenated string of the items in the list (E.g. string.Join("\r\n", listOfStringsProperty);)?

Do I need to customize the entire DataGrid just for this column or can I easily specify the display template just for this property in the C# code?

Comment: @TiagoSousa - Please see updated question with code included :)

Comment: In `Template` make a converter which would take `List<string> ErrorMessages` and join them with comma separation, then assign the result to another `string property`. This shall become your column data

Comment: @o_O with this approach, is there a way to hide the List<string> property from the DataGrid? my understanding is that it will auto generate columns for every property in the Template class.

Comment: Yes it will auto-generate columns for every property, but u can specifically hide the ones u don't want to show. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927093/how-to-hide-automatically-generated-columns-in-datagrid) regarding its implementation

Comment: @JoeSchmidt, you can attach a handler to `AutoGeneratingColumn` event - [see example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358111/datagrid-shows-path-of-image-instead-of-image-itself) - and change generated column. personally I would create a ValueConverter [collection -> string] which uses `string.Join` and add that converter to binding of a generated column

Comment: You could create a specialized collection and override the `ToString` method as a quick fix.

Comment: @o_O Thanks for your help. Created another property with a getter that returns a concatenated list of the strings in the original property and implemented the dataGrid_AutoGenerating column event to hide the other column.

Comment: Great, you can answer your own question, so that future readers might find your post helpful :)